# save a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap

how can we save a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android using Kotlin

Earlier we used

```
 View.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap bmp=  View.getDrawingCache();
```

but now `getDrawingCache` is deprecated

How can we save a view without displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, on Android 9 and 10, I am preparing a WebView off screen, loading html and saving the result to bitmap.

```
// height and width should be >0
val myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    myView.measuredWidth,
    myView.measuredHeight,
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
)
myBitmap.applyCanvas {
    myView.draw(this)
}
```